# can you return a b2Fixture?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Have a function that returns a function and tried to call it like this

_spriteFixture = [self addBoxBodyToSprite:sprite];

However I keep getting an error message stating

HelloWorldLayer.mm:174:20: Assigning to 'b2Fixture *' from incompatible type 'b2Fixture'

my _spriteFixture is a b2Fixture and is declared in the header file. Any ideas what this means or is there a better way to return the fixture?

Thanks

Comment: what about changing the type of `_spriteFixture` from `b2Fixture *` to `b2Fixture` ?

Comment: Then get the following error: Temporary of type 'b2Fixture' has protected destructor

Comment: For any one that wants to know, my method wasnt set to return a pointer 

    -(b2Fixture*)methodName

Instead of 

    -(b2Fixture)methodName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one that wants to know, my method wasnt set to return a pointer -(b2Fixture*)methodName Instead of -(b2Fixture)methodName –

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting that C++ problem where the compiler tries to be helpful by implictly calling your constructor (and then a destructor later).  Tag your constructors as "explicit" to see if that helps.